# Problem with sharp edges after subdivision surface modifier

Tags: subdivision-surface

everybody. I I'm newbie in Blender(obviously=) )
I still got sharp edges after subdivision surface modifier.[image: lower part of lightbulb]

New "smooth" surface (2) kinda attached to some vertices (1) of the mesh, creating ugly vertical edge.[image: mesh wireframe]
Upper part of lightbulb (which was used to creat the lower by "E", RMB, P) have no such problems. [image]There is no double vertices and no Ngons. I've added few horizontal loopcuts(ctrl+R) to sharpen horizontal edges of the mesh, but thats all. I did nothing to vertical edges.  Please help me. This  question drives me crasy. Thanks in advance.

Comment: how does your mesh looks like without modifier? If you've added edge loops between edge loops, it will tend to flatten the surfaces...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I've found an answer. Don't know how, but all normals were mixed up, so modifier went crazy. **Shift+N** solved the problem. [image]

Now I have the habit of checking normals before using any modifiers and posting simple questions =)).